# Set an equal margin-left on each dd within a dl

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a number of definition lists on it. I am attempting to display these like a table with the dt floated to the left of each dd.

I am floating the dt to left of the dd using CSS and have created the below script which calculates the width of the widest dt and sets a left-margin on the dd equal to this width plus 20.

The script works great if there is only one definition list on the page, but when there is more than one, these calculations are applied to all.

How would I apply this calculation to definition lists individually?

Here is my HTML:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Something</dt>
  <dd>ABC</dd>
  <dt>Something else</dt>
  <dd>DEF</dd>
  <dt>And this</dt>
  <dd>GHI</dd>
</dl>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var widest = 0;

jQuery(".dl-horizontal dt").each(function () { 
    widest = Math.max(widest, jQuery(this).outerWidth()+20); 
}).width(widest);

jQuery(".dl-horizontal dd").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).css('margin-left', widest);
});
```

Comment: Put `width(widest)` inside the each, not outside

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve? (Run it below)

```js
var widest = 0;

$(".dl-horizontal dt").each(function () { 
    widest = Math.max(widest, $(this).outerWidth());
})

$(".dl-horizontal dd").css('margin-left', widest+20 ); // no need for "each" to apply CSS
```

```css
dl{
 border: blue solid 1px;
  
}

dt{
   border: green solid 1px;
  display: inline;
}

dd{
 border: red solid 1px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Something</dt>
  <dd>ABC</dd>
  <dt>Something else</dt>
  <dd>DEF</dd>
  <dt>And this</dt>
  <dd>GHI</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks. that works. But if I have more than one definition list, this margin is applied to all. Is there a way to target each list individually?

Comment: Indeed. I assumed you could add some. If you can't or don't want to, use `dt:nth-child(2)`, `dt:nth-child(3)` etc.